# How to redirect a post request in Android using okhttp client

Tags: java, retrofit, okhttp, interceptor

I have gone through this answer [OkHttp doesn't redirect POST requests when used with retrofit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36625178/okhttp-doesnt-redirect-post-requests-when-used-with-retrofit) in order to redirect a post request, more specifically when I got 307 responses. I have created an Interceptor called RedirectURL in order to redirect the requests but it does not work.

```
private static Interceptor redirectRequest() {

    return new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request = chain.request();
            Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
            if (response.code() == 307) {
                Log.d(TAG, "intercept:  is true"+response.code());
                request = request.newBuilder()
                        .url(response.header("Location"))
                        .build();
                response = chain.proceed(request);

            }
            return response;

        }
    };
}
```

**OkkHttp**

```
   private OkHttpClient okHttpClient() {
    RepositoryService repositoryService = new RepositoryService(context);

    return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            // .cache(cache())
            .followRedirects(true)
            .followSslRedirects(true)
            .connectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES) // re-request if package is drop or TimeOut reach 60 seconds
            .readTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .writeTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .addInterceptor(httpsLoggingInterceptor()) // used if network off OR on
            .addInterceptor(redirectRequest())
            .addNetworkInterceptor(repositoryService.networkInterceptor())
            .build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example is creating a new GET request without the body.

The latest OkHttp version should be automatically following a redirect with a 307 response.

https://github.com/square/okhttp/pull/5990/files

Are you testing with a recent version e.g. 4.9.1?